# Listview items are added as columns instead of rows in C# how do I fix?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am having problems with a subborn listview object. I have set it up exactly the same way as one that is functioning properly. The problem is when I add items in with a for each statements they are added as rows instead of columns. Hopefully this is simple.

My constructor code

```
String userstring;

        this.Users.Columns.Add("User");

        foreach (User user in UserListing.userListing)
        {
            userstring = "";
            userstring += user.getUsername() + " "; 
            userstring += " Has Admin Rights:" + user.getRights().ToString() + " "; 
            userstring += " Has Write Access:" + user.getRights().ToString();
            this.Users.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(userstring));
        }
        this.Show();
```

Comment: "added as rows instead of columns" (Question) or "added as column instead of rows" (Title) ?

Comment: What platform do you use: WinForms or WPF or Silverlight?

Comment: I am using WinForms in VS

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I fixed it by changing from

```
myListView.View = View.LargeIcon;
```

to

```
myListView.View = View.Details;
```

Should fix your problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just want to add that I was using the Properties in the Visual Studio and changed View to List. That was solution to my problem.

[Click here to See the Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyGNV.jpg)